# Math notation that I am not familiar with

Tags: exponential-function

I am working on reverse engineering a game and have come across the following formula as a string in a config file:

```
A*(B^xt)+C; xt=A2*x*(T>x)*(B2^x+C2)
```

It would appear that I would solve for `xt` then plug it into the first function. However I don't know how to interpret the `(T>x)`. I have static values for A, B, C, A2, B2, C2, T and they are as follows:

```
A: 300
B: 1.51
C: -319

A2: 1.8
B2: 0.93
C2: -0.64

T: 14
```

I know the outcomes of this equation to be:

```
x = 2, y = 365
x = 3, y = 714
x = 4, y = 1,241
x = 5, y = 2,036
(I can post more if needed)
```

My attempts to plug in the constants and x value (completely ignoring the `(T>x)`) have resulted in values that are not even close to what they are supposed to be. I'm hoping someone here can make sense of it, especially the `(T>x)` part. Thank you for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: Is the game written in a language for which booleans can be evaluated as integers, so `(T>x)` might be 1 (or 0) when T is greater than x, and 0 (or 1) when T is less than or equal to x?

Comment: T>x in some languages evaluates to 1 if true and 0 if false, but that doesn't follow with your assertion. Have you tried posting on http://www.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @OP, are you sure that xt is evaluated by the second formula, then plugged into the first one?  This is a strange order of operations.

Comment: How do you know the outcomes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values you've shown are consistent with `y=A*(B^x)+C`, if we interpret the caret `^` as exponentiation and round to the nearest integer:

```
300*(1.51^2)-319 =  365.03
300*(1.51^3)-319 =  713.885
300*(1.51^4)-319 = 1240.657
300*(1.51^5)-319 = 2036.082
```

So I'm not convinced that this code first computes `xt` and then plugs it into the first part; I'd suppose that the first part is computed first, using a previously established value of `xt` where it happens to be equal to `x`, and then, perhaps, the second part is used to change the value of `xt` to something mysterious.

Comment: If this is the case, then whoever specced out the config file needs a good ritual flailing.

Comment: I feel so incredibly stupid. I don't know why I never just tried to sub x for xt. I checked and the values match all the way up to x=14 (which is the highest x value I have a y for). Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem.  (I didn't think to plug x in for xt either; I just thought I'd try to figure out from the y values what values of xt were being used in the first expression — guessing that `^` was exponentiation, that called for computing `log_B((y-C)/A)`, and those numbers were 2 3 4 5, so... yeah.)

Answer (score 0):

The code `(T > x)` is used in some languages (e.g. MATLAB) as a boolean function, returning `1` when the condition is true, and `0` otherwise.

In other words, `>` is treated as a binary operator mapping $X\times Y$ to $\{0,1\}$.

For instance, if I had `T = 4` and `x = [0 1 2 3 4 5]`, then `T > x` would return `[1 1 1 1 0]`.

Comment: 1. $x$ is a scalar, and 2. your interpretation would suggest that "ignoring" $(T>x)$ would be equivalent to multiplying by $1$, which *should* lead to the right answer; but it doesn't.

Comment: If `x` is a scalar, it makes no difference. `T > x` would just return 1 or 0.